# Does anyone know if buccaneer snap and zippered pants are from the military?

Tags: military

I bought a pair of buccaneer jeans at a household sale for $1. I heard they are from the military. They do have a snap and a zipper. Bell bottoms and 2 pockets on front and back.

Comment: Bell-bottoms seem an unlikely military requirement. Are these items old enough to qualify as "historic"?

Answer (score 2):

The USN began the phasing out bell-bottom dungarees in 1999, by the mid 2000's, they were no longer an authorized article of uniform, replaced by the Navy Working Uniform (NWU), a blue-grey camouflage pattern similar in cut to the Army BDU.

Why did it take so long?  There is a tendency to use available uniforms in the practical supply stock from the time of the beginning of the phase out is exhausted.

I can remember in the late 1960s when bell bottoms were considered stylish, one could go to the base ships store where one could buy uniforms and get a pair at a reasonable price, your choice, zipper fly or button fly, but either buttoned at the waist, no snaps.